# gdal_translate: ERROR 6: Too many command options '–ot'?

Tags: gdal

I am trying to convert a 'cub' file to JPEG, using gdal_translate 2.1.2, on MacOS X 10.12.2, but when I do so I get the error `ERROR 6: Too many command options '–ot'`.

The command line I am using is:

```
gdal_translate –of Jpeg –ot Byte -scale \
  "Venus_Magellan_C3-MDIR_Colorized_Global_Mosaic_4641m.cub" "out.jpg"
```

The ISIS 3 Cube file is downloaded from:

http://astropedia.astrogeology.usgs.gov/download/Venus/Magellan/Colorized/Venus_Magellan_C3-MDIR_Colorized_Global_Mosaic_4641m.cub

The command as entered is based on the documentation here:

http://planetarygis.blogspot.ca/2014/12/what-is-isis-3-cube-format.html

which provides the following examples:

```
gdal_translate –of GTiff input_32bit.cub output_32bit.tif
gdal_translate –of GTiff input_16bit.cub output_16bit.tif
gdal_translate –of GTiff input_8bit.cub output_8bit.tif
gdal_translate –of Jpeg –ot Byte –scale input.cub output_8bit.jpg
gdal_translate –of PNG –ot Byte –scale input.cub output_8bit.png
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong?

Edit: running the apparently same code, I now get:

```
ERROR 6: Too many command options 'Venus_Magellan_C3-MDIR_Colorized_Global_Mosaic_4641m.cub'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76351/gdal-translate-why-jpg-compressed-tif-is-2-times-greater-than-jpg-file) it would appear the documentation is outdated. This worked:

```
gdal_translate -of JPEG "./Venus_Magellan_C3-MDIR_Colorized_Global_Mosaic_4641m.cub" "out.jpg"
```